# Docker how to build an image with dockerfile in ngnix?

Tags: mongodb, docker, nginx, dockerfile, backend

I want to build an image and I have already build my Dockerfile .I already have the container ,but the image is difficult for me to buiold it .this is code for Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

But the problem is , I tried to run it on my terminal (I am using MacBook Terminal) with this command.This code what I wrote in the terminal :

```
Build an image from a Dockerfile
tiadem_tatie@SIT-SMBP1606 ~ % docker run -p 80:80 countly_new
Unable to find image 'countly_new:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
tiadem_tatie@SIT-SMBP1606 ~ % docker build -t Countly_new .  
invalid argument "Countly_new" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
See 'docker build --help'.
tiadem_tatie@SIT-SMBP1606 ~ % docker build -t COUNTLY_NEW .
invalid argument "COUNTLY_NEW" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
See 'docker build --help'.
tiadem_tatie@SIT-SMBP1606 ~ % docker build -t countlynew . 
error checking context: 'can't stat '/Users/tiadem_tatie/.Trash''.
tiadem_tatie@SIT-SMBP1606 ~ % docker build -t <countlynew> .
zsh: no such file or directory: countlynew
tiadem_tatie@SIT-SMBP1606 ~ % docker build -t countlynew path
unable to prepare context: path "path" not found
tiadem_tatie@SIT-SMBP1606 ~ % docker build -t image-name path 
unable to prepare context: path "path" not found
tiadem_tatie@SIT-SMBP1606 ~ % docker build -t image-name path
unable to prepare context: path "path" not found
tiadem_tatie@SIT-SMBP1606 ~ % docker run --help
```

The document Dockerfile is in my downloads folder. Can I have there command and if it is possible , I need help to how to build a mongoDB and Backend .Then I want to connect both together .
Thanky you

Comment: Make a new directory, move the necessary files and the Dockerfile into it, cd into this directory, then run `docker build -t countlynew .`

Answer (score 0):

Why would you keep your project files in `Downloads` folder? It sounds like a horrible idea.

Still, assuming that both your Dockerfile and your website files are located there run the following command to build the image:

```
docker build -t countly_new:latest ~/Downloads
```

Comment: Konrad Botor: I just started with it today and I didn´t no how to i can organize it .

Comment: How can I now  build a database (using mongodb),my frontend and  Backend .i also want to make that , My MongoDB database can be connect to my frontend and Backend without error .But I tried to find some Documentations about it and I didn’t find some concrete .